# Write separate css and js file

Tags: javascript, html

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapsible_animate

has a nice example. I want the first part

```
<style>
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
```

and the javascript part

```
<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

in separate files. I created the first part as test.css and the second part as test.js. I then did

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
```

and

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

but did not work. What should I have done?

Comment: If you have the js and css in separate files, then you should remove the `<style></style>` tags and `<script></script>` tags from those files. Those tags are for when you need to write css and js inside a HTML document directly (they are HTML tags), which is not what you're doing. You have them in proper js and css-files.

Answer (score 0):

In the 'test.css' file you should remove the `<style>`, same for the 'test.js' with the `<script>` tag.

Make sure that the files are in the same level in your folder and then it should work.

You should also put this in the top of your css file:

```
* {
maring: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

}

If it still doesn't work you might want to check if the code is correct. You can do this by just putting everyting in the native html file.

Hope this works!

Comment: So this is what seems to be happening. (1) I set the font color green in css. the original file works. the screen displays green text, (2) I comment out the CSS part and do <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./test.css" media="screen">, then, the text is not green.

Comment: ye okay, then it might be that the css file is not in the same space as your html file. If the file is in a folder or further down in your document it won't work like that. Could you check if this is the case?